# d3.js force-directed graph give TypeError[type] is not defined in d3.v3.js

Tags: css, d3.js, force-layout

I'm new to d3, but learned it by trial.  The following code works fine with the dataset (data/clusterRsult.json) when I do not incorporate any css style.  Now that I would like to have css style for header and footer; and for the content, I would like to have a div on the left for the graph,and a div on the right for detail text of the nodes.  When I added the css style in the previous codes (that works without any div), the Firefox and Google chrome debugger mode give me the error following error: 
[18:09:55.694] TypeError: this[type] is undefined @ file:///C:/Users/mcoyne/workspace_d3js/d3_v3/d3.v3.js:372

===========================

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>Clustering Results - Works</title>
<link href="NSFStyles/nsfstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="d3_v3/d3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3_v3/lib/colorbrewer/colorbrewer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" scr="d3_v3/src/layout/layout.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" scr="d3_v3/src/geom/geom.js"></script>
    <link href="css/nsfstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/csEoSVisContent.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<style>
     p {
        -webkit-margin-after: 0em;
        -webkit-margin-before: 0em;
        margin-bottom: 0em;
        margin-top: 5em;
    }
    #h_emphasis01 {
        font-weight: bold;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="csnsfheader"></div>
<div style="text-align: right; padding-right: 1em; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 60%; top:auto;vertical-align: top; font-weight: bold; padding-top: 1px" id="Help" align="right">
                                    <a style="text-decoration: none" href="helpEos.html"
                                        target="_blank">HELP | </a><a style="text-decoration: none" title="Send us an email"href="mailto:xyz@abc.gov">CONTACT |</a>
</div>

<div class = "svg"> 

    <div class="csnsfbody.svg.containerLeft" id="clusterLeftPanel"> </div>
    <div class="csnsfbody.svg.containerRight" id="clusterRightPanel"> </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3_v3/d3.v3.js"></script>
    <!--script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script-->

    <script>

            var width = 620,
                height = width,
                radius = Math.min(width, height) /2,
                node,
                link,
                root,
                x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, 2 * Math.PI]),
                y = d3.scale.pow().exponent(1.3).domain([0,1]).range([0, radius]);
                // y = d3.scale.linear().range([0, radius]),
                padding = 5,
                duration = 1000,
                color = d3.scale.category20c();


            var colorScaleTop = d3.scale.ordinal().domain([101, 1000.0]).range(colorbrewer.Dark2[5]);
            var colorScaleMiddle = d3.scale.ordinal().domain([1, 1000.0]).range(colorbrewer.Pastel1[6]);
            var colorScaleLeaf = d3.scale.ordinal().domain([1]).range(colorbrewer.Set2[5]);


                // set up the left section of the screen for the graph
            var vis = d3.select("body")
                        .append ("csnsfbody.svg.containerLeft")       
                        .attr("class", "csnsfbody.svg.containerLeft")
                        .style("width", width + "px")
                                .style("height", height + "px")
                        .append("svg:svg")
                        .attr("width", width + padding * 2 )
                        .attr("height", height + padding * 2)
                    .append("svg:g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + [radius + padding, radius + padding] + ")")
                        ; 

           // set up the right section of the screen for text displaying
           var clusterDetails = d3.select("body")
                                    .append("csnsfbody.svg.containerRight")
                            .attr("class", "csnsfbody.svg.containerRight")
                    .style("width", width + "px")
                                .style("height", height + "px")
                    .style("margin-left", "100px")
                                                                                                        .style("background","#F8FBEF") 
                                    .style("position", "absolute")
                                   ;

            // *** Error encounter on this line
            // *** 
            d3.json("data/clusterResult.json", function(error, json) {
           if (error) return console.log("there was an error loading the data: " + error);


                var force = d3.layout.force()
                .size([width, height])
                .charge(function(d) { return getCharge(d);})
                .linkDistance(function(d) { return getLinkDistance(d); })
                .on("tick", tick)
                .on("mouseover",mouseover)
                .on("mouseout", mouseout)
                ;

              // successfully load data from data.json
              console.log("there are " + json.size + " nodes in my dataset");
              console.log("there are " + json.children.length + " categories in my dataset");
              root = json;
              update();
            });

            function update() {
              var nodes = flatten(root),
                  links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes),
                  total = nodes.length || 1;

                console.log("nodes.length = " + nodes.length);
                console.log("total=" + total);



              // Restart the force layout.
              force
                  .gravity(Math.atan(total / 50) / Math.PI * 0.4) 
                  .nodes(nodes)
                  .links(links)
                  .start();

              // Update the links
             // link = vis.selectAll("line.link")
             //   .data(force.links())
             //   .attr("class", "link")

                     link = svg.selectAll('.link')
                                .data( force.links() )
                        .enter().append('line')
                            .attr('class', 'link')
                        .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });
                        ;
              // Enter any new links.
              link.enter().insert("svg:line", ".node")
                  .attr("class", "link")
                  .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                  .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                  .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                  .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

              // Exit any old links.
              link.exit().remove();

              // Update the nodes
              node = vis.selectAll("circle.node")
                .data(force.nodes())
                .classed("collapsed", function(d) { return d._children ? 1 : 0; })
                .attr("class", "node")
                .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d);} )
                ;

              node.select ("circle")
                  .style("fill",   function(d) { return color(d);} );


              // Enter any new nodes.
              var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("svg:g")
                  .attr("class", "node")
                  .call(force.drag)
                ;

             nodeEnter.append("svg:circle")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .classed('directory', function(d) { return (d._children || d.children) ? 1 : 0; })
                .attr("r", function(d) {return getRadius(d); })
                .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d); })
                .call(force.drag)
                //.on("click",click)  // This is NOT working
                ;

             nodeEnter.append("svg:text")
                      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                      .attr("dy", ".35em")
                      .style("font-size", function (d) {  return  d.children ? "12px" : "8px"; })
                      .style("font-weight", function (d) {  return  d.children ? "600" : "200"; })
                      .text(function(d) {return  d.children ?  (d.name + " (" + d.size + ")") : ""; });

              // Exit any old nodes
              node.exit().remove();


              // reselect for update
              link = vis.selectAll("line.link");
              node = vis.selectAll("g.node");
              force.on("tick", tick);


            } // end update function

            function tick() {
                       link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                       .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                       .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                       .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

                       node.attr("transform", function(d) {
                                      return "translate(" + Math.max(5, Math.min(width - 5, d.x)) + "," + Math.max(5, Math.min(height - 5, d.y)) + ")";
                                      });
            }

            // Color leaf nodes orange, and packages white or blue.

            function color(d) {

                //if (d.type=="root") {return colorScaleTop(d.children);}
                //if (d.type == "label") {return colorScaleMiddle (d.children);}

                if (d.type == "root" ){return "#FFFF33"; }

                if (d.type == "label") {
                    if (d.size <= 50) { return "#7FBF7B"; }  // good color 66C2A5, cute green A1D76A
                    if (d.size > 50 && d.size <= 100) { return "#FC8D62"; }
                    if (d.size > 100) { return "#E9A3C9"; }
                }

                if (d.type == "leaf") {return "#2C7FB8"; }  // lavender #BEAED4
                                                            // light green ADDD8E


            }

            function getRadius (d) {
                    if (d.type == "root") {return 20;}
                    if (d.type == "label") {return 12; }
                    if (d.type == "leaf") {return 2;}
            }

            function getLinkDistance (d) {

                    if (d.target.type == "label") {return 8; }
                    if (d.target.type == "leaf") {return 3;}
            }


            function getCharge (d) {
                if (d.type == "root") {return -300; }
                if (d.type == "label") {return -600; }
                if (d.type == "leaf") {return -40;}
            }


            // Toggle children on click.
            function click(d) {
              if (d.children) {

                d._children = d.children;
                d.children = null;

              } else {
                d.children = d._children;
                d._children = null;
              }
              update();
            }

            function mouseover (d) {
                if (d.type == "leaf") {
                    this.text.attr('transform', 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + (d.y - 5 - (d.children ? 3.5 : Math.sqrt(d.size) / 2)) + ')')
                    .text(d.name)
                    //.style('display', null)
                    ;

                }

            }

            // Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
            function flatten(root) {
              var nodes = [], i = 0;

              function recurse(node) {
                if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
                if (!nodes.id) nodes.id = ++i;
                nodes.push(node);
              }

              recurse(root);
              return nodes;
            }
             function mouseover(d)
             {
                console.log("mouseouver <" + d.name + ">");


                if (d.type == "root") {
                             console.log("mouseouver, root <" + d.name + ">");

                             clusterDetais.append("p")
                                          .style("font-weight", 600)
                                          .text(d.name);
                 }
                if (d.type== "label") {
                    console.log("mouseouver, label <" + d.name + ">");




                    clusterDetails.append("p")
                                  .style("font-weight", 600)
                                  .text("Cluster Name: " + d.name + " (" + d.size + ")")
                                 ;
                    var myChildren = new Array;
                    myChildren = getChildrenOf(d, myChildren);
                    for (var i = 0; i < myChildren.length; i++) {
                          if (myChildren[i].type === "label" && myChildren[i].children) {
                               clusterDetails.append("p")
                                             .style("font-weight", 600)
                                             .text ("Sub-cluster name: " + myChildren[i].name + " (" + myChildren[i].size + ")")
                               ;
                          }
                          else { clusterDetails.append("p")
                                               .text(myChildren[i].name);
                          }

                    }  // end for

                }                                                     
                if(d.type=="leaf" ){
                    clusterDetails.append("p")
                                  .text  ("Proposal id: " + d.name)
                                  .text  ("Title: " + "TBA")
                                  .text  ("PI/CoPi: " + "TBA")
                    ;
                }

             }  // end mouseover

             //mouseout function which removes the values and replaces them with a blank space

             function mouseout(d)
             {

                clusterDetails.html(' ');

             }



    </script>
</div>
<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!-- Footer                                                                 -->
<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<div class="csnsffooter" >
<!-- Add footer here -->
<span></span>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't `.append ("csnsfbody.svg.containerLeft")` -- this is not a valid HTML element.

Comment: Hi Lars, Thank you for correcting, by removing the .append ("csnsfbody.svg.containerLeft") and its style, I still have the error TypeError: this[Type] is undefined at d3.v3.js:372.

Comment: Have you verified that your `nodes` are the data structure expected by `d3.layout.tree().links()`?

Comment: Hi Lars, The error happens before nodes is reached.  Previously I coded the Vis as follows:  var vis = d3.select("#csnsfbody.svg.containerLeft").append("svg:svg")
           .attr("width", width)
           .attr("height", height)
        .append("svg:g")  the forced directed graph appears and everything works as coded.  This is why I don't think there is a problem with the data (hence links and nodes).  However, I can be wrong in that thinking.

Comment: There must be something else that has changed.

Comment: Seems like data error. Expand the stack trace, it'll tell you where the error in you code is.